# Can a magnetic field affect other magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If I have square loop wire with current flowing , can the magnetic field of one segment of a wire mess with other's magnetic field?

If I were to take an observation point perpendicular to a segment wire and at a very far distance, can I just add the magnetic field of 2 (somewhat) perpendicular wire together and omit the 2 (somewhat) parallel wire's $B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electromagnetic fields obey the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). The magnetic field is at any point in space is therefore the linear combination of the magnetic fields emanating from each of the sources, i.e. segments of wire.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder if one should specify electromagnetic fields _in vacuum_. I vaguely know that, in the presence of matter, electromagnetic equations can become non-linear, meaning the superposition principle does not hold anymore.